# JAXB: Import own class into generated Class

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm using JAXB 2.2 and I'm into some trouble.

I have the following XML in my xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="Party" abstract="true">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <ci:code>
                public ElectronicAddress
                getFirstPrimaryElectronicAddressPhone() {
                for (ElectronicAddress
                eAddress : electronicAddresses) {
                if (checkRefCodeTypeCode(eAddress,
                CodeHelper.ADDRTYPEELECORG_PHONE_CODE,
                CodeHelper.ADDRTYPEELECPERS_PHONE_CODE)) {
                return eAddress;
                }
                }
                return
                null;
                }
          [...]
```

Now, I need to import my own (CodeHelper) class into the generated class, because CodeHelper is not in the same package as the generated source.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly write an XJC plugin to get this behaviour. The link below has some pointers for creating a plugin:

- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html

The example in the above article is actually a code injector plug-in.

Comment: So you mean, that JAXB is not able to insert custom imports out of the box?

Comment: @Leonard Butz - The JAXB spec (JSR-222) does not cover inserting code blocks in the way that you describe.  However the XJC tool that is provided by the JAXB reference implementation does provide a custom plugin mechanism.  This plugin mechanism should let you do what you are looking for.